# How to export more than 1MB in XML format using sqlcmd and without an input file?

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, export, sqlcmd

In SQL Server 2008, I want to export the result of a stored procedure to a file using **sqlcmd** utility. Now the end of my stored procedure is a select statement with a "for xml path.." clause at the end.

I read on [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) that if I don't want my output truncated when reaching 1MB file size, I have to use this **:XML ON** command, but it should be placed on its own line, before calling the stored procedure.

- Does any of you experts know if it is possible to do that without specifying an input file for sqlcmd? (I'm calling sqlcmd like this:

`exec master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -Q"exec storedProcedureName @param1=value1, @param2=value2" -o c:\exportResults.xml -h-1 -E'`,

but "storedProcedureName" and its parameters can change, which would mean 1 input file per passed parameters to sqlcmd)

- Also, it seems that I can't use bcp instead of sqlcmd because my stored procedure is creating a temporary table and performing DML statements on it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question (using powershell):

http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/5322/is-it-possible-to-use-the-xml-on-option-without-using-an-input-file/5380#5380

Comment: [here it is](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/6454/is-it-possible-to-use-the-xml-on-option-without-us.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use powershell as your executing shell, then you can have the `:XML ON` in the `-Q` parameter as well, just encode endline character `\\n` (`n in powershell)

```
sqlcmd -Q":XML ON\`n exec storedProcedureName @param1=value1, @param2=value2" -o c:\exportResults.xml -h-1 -E
```