# How to prevent sqlcmd truncation with for xml path query result

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, batch-file, for-xml-path

After reading [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856260/for-xml-path-results-in-ssms-truncated-to-2034-characters) and [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533552/how-to-export-more-than-1mb-in-xml-format-using-sqlcmd-and-without-an-input-file) and the [infopage on sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) I still cannot get the following to work.

I am trying to query a result into a xml file using a sqlcmd in batch file.

The batchfile looks like this:

```
sqlcmd -R -d DBName -i "c:\inputquery.sql" -h-1 -y 0 -o "c:\outputfile.xml"
```

The simplicated sql query is:

```
:XML ON
SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
CAST((
SELECT Columns FROM Table
FOR XML PATH ('Product'), ROOT('Products')
) 
AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

The output is a xml file of about 1025Kb whit a truncated string. I think it truncates to 1mb, but how can you prevent this? The goal is to get the full query result into the xml file. As far as I know, all options are used already. Using TSQL SSMS2008 by the way.

Comment: If you're just working in SSMS, then there are options to control how much XML data can be returned.  1MB, 2MB, 5MB or Unlimited.  See Tools | Options | Query Results | SQL Server | Results to Grid | XML data.  It doesn't have an option for "Results to File".  But perhaps you could run the query to the Grid, and then save the results?

Comment: If you use SSMS only then that would work, but I need to automate the process with a batch file. The SSMS settings don't have effect on the sqlcmd outcome. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I've used BCP to do things like this.  Here's a BCP example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2586615/822072

Comment: Yes that's also a possibilty, I tried BCP, didn't work, but just found out xp_cmdshell is not active, see what it does if I fix that. I will try with SSIS package also. http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-xml.htm#SQL%20Server%20Data%20Export%20to%20XML%20using%20SQLCMD

Comment: After exhausting all visible options to **sqlcmd.exe** and SSMS, I wrote a Java program to extract the XML column I needed. Hardly a universal solution, but it got this job done.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today, I used the -y0 option.  My output looks correct now.  Thought I would post my findings so it might help others running into the same thing.

```
sqlcmd -Sxxxxxxx -E -dmaster -h-1 -y0 -Q" my query that produces long results in here;" > "D\:out.txt"
```

`-h-1` removes the column headers too.

Comment: `-y0`'s maximum is one megabyte. (I've got the same problem as OP where 1048676 characters are not enough.)

Comment: When I tried using `-h-1` and `-y0` I got this error message: `Sqlcmd: The -h and the -y 0 options are mutually exclusive.`. Although it seems like even without `-h-1` the header is excluded anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Using `-y0` by itself opened up the widest column so far to 664,241. I don't know what the limit is, but this seems quite good. The `-h-1` is for no headers.

```
sqlcmd -S XXXXX -E -o test.txt -i SelectStmt.spl -h-1 -y0
```

The `SelectStmt.spl` has 40 fields and one field is a binary picture which is why one column width is so wide.

Answer (score -1):

You need to output your XML as XML type. Normally, that is done using `TYPE` directive in addition to `FOR XML`. But if you want to add the Xml declaration, you will have to put everything into an xml variable then select that. Ex:

```
declare @xml as xml
select @xml = cast(('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>'+cast((SELECT Columns FROM Table FOR XML PATH ('Product'), ROOT('Products')) as nvarchar(max))) as xml)

select @xml
```

**Edit**: Sorry. Adding Xml declaration will not work because Sql presents the stream as XML in its native encoding (UTF-16) and it will strip off any declaration.

**Edit**: